# How do I access content ( DOM node ) of mapped div in react in Functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, dom, ref

My Code : https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-wescoff-44n2by?file=/src/App.js

When I hover over any element, always the last element of array is printed in console.

I tried using ref, not sure if I am doing it right.

---

I expected on hover over any element that elements content will be console logged.

*Please suggest any way on how to access any elements content on hover.*

Comment: Relevant code should be included in the question. I mean... you only have one ref.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can achieve it without using useRef as follows:

```
  const array = [12,34,54,122,0];

  function enterMouse(event){
    console.log(event.target.innerHTML)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {
        array.map((e,index)=>
        <h1 key={index} onMouseEnter={enterMouse}>{e}</h1>)
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the index of the current element as an argument to the enterMouse function.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const array = [12, 34, 54, 122, 0];
  const myRef = useRef(null);

  function enterMouse(index) {
    console.log(array[index]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {array.map((e, index) => (
        <h1
          onMouseEnter={() => {
            enterMouse(index);
          }}
          ref={myRef}
        >
          {e}
        </h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank very much for your time and effort. Have a nice day